# Create a file inside a directory with a PHP script

Tags: php

In one of my site I use a PHP script that creates a cache file, my question is can I store those .html files inside a directory?

This is my script:

(top-cache.php)

```
<?php
$cachefile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'];
$cachefile = md5($cachefile).".html";
$cachetime = 1800;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    include($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
?>
```

(bottom-cache.php)

```
<?php
// Cache the contents to a file
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
?>
```

the only problem is that it creates the files in the root directory, can I make it that it will creates those cache file inside a directory?

For exemple:

My cache file is in the directory /root/top-cache.php and it creates those files in /root/cache/nameofthecachefile.php

Comment: check this site
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/

Comment: `$cached = fopen(__DIR__."/".$cachefile, 'w');` will put the file in the directory of the actual script, if it gets included etc.

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify any directory to save the cache

```
$cachedir = '/cache/'; // Directory to cache files in (keep outside web root)
$cachefile = $cachedir.md5($cachefile).".html";
```